# Add Multiple specific time in crontab by python programming

Tags: python-2.7

I want to add multiple time( at hour like 12,13,14) in crontab using python2.7.8. How can I do that .

```
 for job in cron.find_comment(cron_id):
            job.hour.on(int ('5'))
            job.minute.on(int ('30'))
"""It displaying 
"30 5 * * * '/export/home/www/current/abc.sh' # IMPORT_TUD
"
"""
#And I am trying to do like....

for job in cron.find_comment(cron_id):
            job.hour.on(int ('5,6,7'))
            job.minute.on(int ('30'))
"""Output should be like this..
```

"30 5,6,7 * * * '/export/home/www/current/abc.sh' # IMPORT_TUD
 "
But It's not working """

## This is code working for single hour entry.... Its working fine but now I have

time like this ['13:00:00','14:00:00','15:00:00']

```
    if daily_job > 0:

        sched_str = sched_str.replace(r'",', r",") # this replaces ", with ;
        sched_str = sched_str.replace(r'"', '')

        time_str = sched_str.split(':')

        for job in cron.find_comment(cron_id):
            job.hour.on(int(time_str[0]))
            job.minute.on(int(time_str[1]))
```

Comment: If you have an image, please put it in the post directly. What have you tried already?

Comment: I am posting question first time so, I don't know how to add image

Comment: You cannot post an an image, because you need >50 (IIRC) reputation to do so. You should not be posting images of text anyway, rather paste it directly into your question and use the code button (`{}`) to format it. Also, please show what effort you have made to code this yourself - SO is not the place for "Write my code for me" requests.

Comment: if daily_job > 0:
  
            sched_str = sched_str.replace(r'",', r",") # this replaces ", with ;
            sched_str = sched_str.replace(r'"', '')
   
            time_str = sched_str.split(':')
   
            for job in cron.find_comment(cron_id):
                job.hour.on(int(time_str[0]))
                job.minute.on(int(time_str[1]))

Answer (score 0):

```
I found two approach:
1. If we want No. times = No. of cronTab entry like...  
   30 3 * * * '/etc/crontab/abc.sh' # hello
   30 4 * * * '/etc/crontab/abc.sh' # hello
   30 5 * * * '/etc/crontab/abc.sh' # hello



        file_cron.remove_all(comment='hello')
        for i in sched_str:
            time_str = i.split(':')
            cur_hour = int (time_str[0])
            cur_minute = int (time_str[1])
            cron_job = file_cron.new('/etc/crontab', comment='hello')
            cron_job.hour.on(cur_hour)
            cron_job.minute.on(cur_minute)

            file_cron.write()
2. For single line of cronTab like (30 3,4,5,6 * * *'/etc/crontab/abc.sh' # hello)

        file_cron = CronTab(tabfile='filename.tab')
        sched_hour = ['11','13','15']

        def one():
            cron_job.hour.on(sched_hour[0])

        def two():
            cron_job.hour.on(sched_hour[0],sched_hour[1])

        def three():
            cron_job.hour.on(sched_hour[0],sched_hour[1],sched_hour[2])


        options = {1: one,
                   2: two,
                   3: three,
                   }

        a = len(sched_hour)
        for cron_job in file_cron.find_comment('hello'):
            options[a]()
            cron_job.minute.on(40)

        file_cron.write()
```